# JQuery selector for text in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select `8:30 space` with space that comes from server, I want to select and trim that space and insert it back.

I have tried selecting it like `$('.time-wrapper').text()` it give me all text also `.prev()` and `.next()` with `$('.time-wrapper span').prev();` and `$('.time-wrapper br').next()` but its not helping also challenge will be insert it back there.

```
<span class="time-wrapper">8:30 <span>&nbsp;am</span>&nbsp;PT  </span>
```

Any help is appreciated. If I am not clear do ask in comments.

Comment: Note that word "space" in 8:30 space is written in order to demonstrate that there is space.

Comment: "but its not helping" by this do you mean the space is still there? you could use it to get the text then regex `.replace()` to remove/reinsert

Comment: @Aamir Shahzad  actually what would you like to do can clearify by demo code ? or js fiddle.?

Comment: Simply, I want to remove space after 8:30 before the span. That comes from server.

Comment: For the sake of clarity - I believe Aamir just wants to remove the trailing space from the time, but leaving the preceding spans and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var textnode= $('.time-wrapper').contents().first()[0]; //get javascript object of text node
textnode.textContent = textnode.textContent.trim(); //trim and replace text
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwcp8p6j/)**

Comment: This will need an update if there will be more than one `.time-wrapper` classes in the same document (I don't know if it is a requirement at all).

Comment: OP can write the above snippet in each condition.